# Help me realize this inequality of infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Can you help me realize why this is true? I can tell you that $P_i$ and $P_j$ are probabilities, i.e. $0 \leq P_i, P_j \leq 1$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty ijP_iP_j \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2P_jP_i$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a given pair $(m,n)$ with $m\ne n$, consider the sum of the two terms corresponding to $(i,j) = (m,n)$ and $(i,j)=(n,m)$.  For the summation on the left, this will be
$$
mnP_mP_n + nmP_nP_m = 2mnP_mP_n,
$$
while for the sum on the right this will be
$$
n^2P_n P_m + m^2 P_m P_n = (n^2+m^2)P_mP_n.
$$
Since $2mn \le m^2+n^2$ for all $m$ and $n$, it follows that
$$
\sum_{i \ne j} ijP_iP_j \le \sum_{i\ne j} j^2 P_j P_i.
$$
But
$$
\sum_{i = j} ijP_iP_j = \sum_{i = j} j^2 P_j P_i,
$$
so this proves the given inequality.